# Тварина жере чи їсть?

Tags: вживання-слів, ненормативна-лексика

Такі слова, як "лапа", "морда", "шкіритися", "дохнути" є цілком нормальними для тварин. Та застосувавши їх до людей, замість слів "рука", "обличчя", "усміхатися" і "вмирати" відповідно, вони стають лайливими.
Слово "жерти" позначається у словниках, як вульгарне, зневажливе. А чи стане воно нормативним, якщо буде застосовано до тварини?
Людина їсть їжу, а тварина жере корм.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово "жерти" є синонімом слова "їсти" (жадібно їсти), тому "тварина жере корм" - правильна конструкція, що означає, що тварина їсть їжу. Проте у розмовній мові більш часто використовується слово "їсти", тому фраза "тварина їсть корм" звучить більш природньо.